# App swipe away handler in PWA

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, progressive-web-apps, dom-events

Is there any way to get an handle to app swipe away (killing the app) in PWA which is added to home screen (on Android and iOS). I would like to perform few tasks on destroy(?) of the app (Mostly involves resetting data in local-storage).

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the `unload` event?

Comment: I'm using `beforeunload` event. Will try `unload` check.

Comment: While using `unload` event, even if we refresh the page, this get triggered. So I cannot use this event. Is there any particular event when the browser get closed?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? It looks like app state is not completely destroyed if the user "kills" the app by swiping it up and away.